# get_the_post_thumbnail_url() not working when adding an image size

Tags: wordpress

I have a weird situation when I am trying to use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` in Wordpress.

To be more precise, I have this variable:

```
$postImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('article-thumbnail-image');
```

and it returns a blank value. If I use:

```
$postImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

the value returned is correct but it has a different image size (150x150). Now the weird part is if I use:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url('article-thumbnail-image');
```

it shows the right value as this image size is registered in `functions.php` but I need to use the GET function.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two arguments in get_the_post_thumbnail_url(). You'll need to either use null or the post_id/post for the first argument and the size would be the second.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: `$postImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('', 'article-thumbnail-image');`  that worked.